# How do i get data from infobox?

Tags: python, html, node.js

It is necessary to find an article on Wiki and pull out the name for this level of classification from the table

I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_infobox(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

   tble = bs.find('table', {'class' :'infobox'})
   result = {}
   row_count = 0
   if table is None:
     pas
   else:
     for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
         if tr.find('th'):
             pass
         else:
             row_count += 1
     if row_count > 1:
         if tr is not None:
           result[tr.find('td').text.stip()] = tr.find('td').text
     return result

print(urol(""))
```

Comment: Could you please share what doesn't work for you?

Comment: I can't get information from the infobox. I get this: {'Notes': 'Notes'}

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the row has exactly two columns seems to be the easiest way. That works for me:

```
def get_infobox(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    table = bs.find('table', {'class': 'infobox'})
    result = {}
    
    if table is None:
        return None
    
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        if len(tds) == 2:
            key, value = tds
            result[key.text.strip()] = value.text.strip()
    return result

print(get_infobox("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat"))
```

Result:

```
{'Kingdom:': 'Animalia', 'Phylum:': 'Chordata', 'Class:': 'Mammalia', 'Order:': 'Carnivora', 'Suborder:': 'Feliformia', 'Family:': 'Felidae', 'Subfamily:': 'Felinae', 'Genus:': 'Felis', 'Species:': 'F.\xa0catus[1]'}
```

You can clean up results as necessary.

Comment: Yes! This is what I need, thanks! But if I change the language of the wikipedia link to another one, for example from eng to ua, then the result is an empty { }

Comment: Noticed that for other languages (e.x. Ukrainian), the table doesn't have class "infobox". You can try finding a table without a class filter and hope that it's the first table on the page.

Comment: But the ru language has an infobox, but also the result is an empty array like { }

Comment: Russian page has a completely different structure to it. So you'd need to implement different crawling functions for each language. Or you can try a propper Wikipedia API (e.x. [Manual:Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot))

Answer (score 0):

For Russian page you can do like this:

```
def get_infobox(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')
    return dict(x.getText().split(":") for x in bs.findAll('div', class_='ts-Taxonomy-rang-row'))


print(get_infobox('https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0'))
```